# Can I use Ransack to search for the same value in multiple columns?

Tags: ruby, ransack

Can the Ransack gem generate a SQL search of multiple columns for the same value?

For instance, something like "users where the first name OR the last name contains 'James'".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, here is an example:

```
MyModel.search(:firstname_or_lastname_cont => "James").result
```

Comment: Awesome. The documentation on Ransack is not very thorough yet. We added this to the wiki: https://github.com/ernie/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching